# Finding a memory leak in a very big project

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I have a pretty big multithreading Python project that apparently has a memory leak somewhere. A `DoctorThread` shows me these (shortened) results:

```
Partition of a set of 418 objects. Total size = 96792 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0     43  10    22792  24     22792  24 guppy.etc.Glue.Interface
     1     66  16    18480  19     41272  43 dict of guppy.etc.Glue.Owner
     2     25   6    18344  19     59616  62 dict of guppy.etc.Glue.Share
     3      8   2     8384   9     68000  70 guppy.etc.Glue.Share
     4     86  21     6696   7     74696  77 dict (no owner)
     5     22   5     6160   6     80856  84 guppy.etc.Glue.Owner
     6     37   9     2608   3     83464  86 dict (no owner), dict of guppy.etc.Glue.Interface
     7     28   7     2464   3     85928  89 guppy.heapy.heapyc.HeapView
     8     11   3     1840   2     87768  91 <Nothing>
     9      2   0     1112   1     88880  92 __builtin__.cell
<24 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
Partition of a set of 23178 objects. Total size = 1604224 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  11135  48   801440  50    801440  50 list
     1  11153  48   602408  38   1403848  88 tuple
     [...]
<95 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
Partition of a set of 45140 objects. Total size = 2987568 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  22114  49  1591936  53   1591936  53 list
     1  22133  49  1195328  40   2787264  93 tuple
     [...]
<95 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
Partition of a set of 66115 objects. Total size = 4337720 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  32524  49  2341216  54   2341216  54 list
     1  32513  49  1755848  40   4097064  94 tuple
     [...]
<104 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
Partition of a set of 88355 objects. Total size = 5739128 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  43644  49  3141856  55   3141856  55 list
     1  43633  49  2356328  41   5498184  96 tuple
     [...]
<104 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
Partition of a set of 110380 objects. Total size = 7097992 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  54734  50  3940576  56   3940576  56 list
     1  54753  50  2956808  42   6897384  97 tuple
     [...]
<97 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

As you can see, the number of `list` and `tuple` referrers increases gradually. And it never stops increasing. These two entries are the only ones that increase constantly.

The DoctorThread class looks like this:

```
class DoctorThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DoctorThread, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.hp = guppy.hpy()

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        logging.info("Doctor Thread started - taking heap snapshots")
        before_heap = self.hp.heap()

        while not PippinNetwork.is_shutdown():
            gc.collect()
            leftover = self.hp.heap() - before_heap
            print(leftover.byrcs)
            time.sleep(2.0)
```

Memory consumption is equally increasing. How can I find the culprit of this leak?

### Update: solved.

In hindsight it was a rampant `list.append((object, object))`. The guppy results could have been interpreted like that.

Comment: when trying to find needles in a haystack, it helps if you can throw away most of the haystack. I'd say, start chopping away code logic and rechecking to make sure the behaviour still exists? Full disclaimer though, i have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: Found it that way. It was an unconstrained list.append() call... Thank you!

Comment: glad to hear! :)

Answer (score 1):

In case of memory leak in big source codes you can use 'pympler' in python to track for the reference in future work.

```
from pympler import muppy

 from pympler import summary

all_objects = muppy.get_objects()

sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)
 summary.print_(sum1)
```

[image]

you can filter objects as well. Only include those where you have doubt then you can see which object or variable is causing memory leak then see the logic behind that.

I am suggesting this method cause in this way you don't have to cut down the logic (cause your project would have the huge code)

In case of clarification, you can ask in comment.

Comment: Thank you. For the next time that this happens I will be armed and know what I'll have to look for. Especially if it behaves like in this case (growing list referrer). The question that remains though is, if I have lots of lists and lots of `list.append` calls. How do I figure out which one goes postal? Only manually or does `muppy` help with that as well? A possibility to split the summary into calls that change the corresponding list to see which one is growing... something like that.

Comment: if you have list inside list that means in case of problem your last list in hierarchy is the problem, in the start you can go with bigger object for example with the main objects where possibility of list inside list later whichever grow meaninglessly take the summary of inner objects this can be done via summary traverse as well but that traverse code you have to write according to your object hierarchy